# System.NotImplementedException: 'This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly

Tags: xamarin.forms, notimplementedexception

I have added `Plugin.MediaManager` and `Plugin.MediaManager.Forms` into my `xamarin forms` project for playing video.

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
```

when I am trying to add above code, it shows error (No overload for method Init();)

But getting below exception on android when running the project with below line of code.

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();
```

> System.NotImplementedException: 'This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.'

IOS and UWP apps are working fine, only android project has this issue. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Have you install nuget package to  Android project?

Comment: @PhatHuynh That packages are also showing on the android project.

Comment: This link could be helpful: [Current is not implemented](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/issues/437)

Comment: @PhatHuynh nothing helps me

Comment: What is the version of your xamarin.forms in share project and specific platforms?

Comment: Make sure that you update the version of Xamarin.Forms in Android project to 4.2.x .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes it is 4.2.0.815419

Comment: Share you sample and I will check it .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IVFwV0usob-eLfFmjPvPXXfpBTKGnc2g

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Fixed, the problem is with the target framework of android project. I set the compile using android version to Android 9.0 and problem solved.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Can you please post it as your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Also can you please check why the following video link is not playing on the app. public string videourl = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/361089481"; I have added this link on the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> System.NotImplementedException: 'This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.'

The above error often appears when the version of Android target is lower . Here is a similar issue that you can check https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/issues/437 .

In addition, in your case . You should make sure the format of video url is xxx.mp4 .The plugin couldn't support the url with such a format(player.vimeo.com/video/361089481).

Comment: Is there any way of playing video without the video format?

Comment: You can use a WebView and play the video in it.But it will be a little complex .

Answer (score 3):

I have updated the compile version to 10.0 and worked for me.

Android project referring to the net standard 2.0, So the init method was not taking a parameter. I looked into the plugin.mediamanager package folder for android dll and it was monoandroid10.0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On previous versions of this plugin the init for Android
is:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();
```

I just updated all packages in nuget including xamarin.forms, changed the Target framework to API 29 and changed in Android the

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();
```

to

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
```

and works now.

- Plugin.MediaManager v0.9.7
- Plugin.MediaManager.Forms v0.9.7
- Xamarin.Forms v4.5.0.495